# How to force numeration in tables and figs

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, wrapfigure, numeration

[image]

[image]

Hello Friends I would like to force the enumeration in figs and tables: I need Figura 1 y tabla 1. I am using report class but my tables and figs took the chapter enumeration too: Tabla II:1. and is wrong I need tabla 1 whit ordinals numbers only: tabla 1. and my figs too onli figura 1. Can you help me?

Comment: You can add to your preamble `counterwithout{figure}{chapter}`, and similarly for tables.

Comment: Not functioned me :(

Comment: Could you post a small complete code showing your problem? (including your document class).

Comment: Precisely, this behaviour may depend on the document class or on a package you load.

Comment: Wow!! I repeat for table and function!!! thank you so much!! Is good now.

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad when I can help!

Comment: could you help me with my other questions?

Comment: of course, if I can, but what are these other questions?

Comment: I need ajust the size font in \listfigurename becouse the tittle is bigger. I have been trying with \tiny:  \renewcommand{\listtablename}{\tiny {Índice de tablas}} but I cant.

Comment: You should take a look at `titletoc`, a companion package of `titlesec`.

Comment: hello,  can you help me? my chapter name is glued with the number: CAPÍTULOV, CAPÍTULOVIII, I need CAPÍTULO VIII with spacing.

Comment: could you post a short, yet complete, code showing your problems.